# How Can I Add Different Icons to Child Elements in Expandable ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have created an Expandable ListView for my app following this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

I'm wanting to add different icons for each child aligned to the right, how can I do this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `list_item.xml` from the article you've posted just put the needed drawable on the right of `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:drawableRight[End]="@drawable/my_cool_drawable"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If every item should have different drawable, then just set it in the runtime, by using [setCompoundDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method:

```
txtListChild.setCompoundDrawable(null, null, myCoolDrawable, null);
```

You may want to specify `drawablePadding` as well. Btw, `LinearLayout` in the example from the article is useless, you can use `FrameLayout` instead or even check `merge` tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, in which file do I place this code?

Comment: @Spartan123 By looking on the article you've posted I would say that at the place, where you bind data to the child view. It is `getChildView` in the `ExpandableListAdapter.java`. The same place where you set text for the child.